# Very thin page borders/margin when printing from Safari

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, printing, safari, print-to-pdf

Whenever I print (or save something as PDF) from Safari 5.0.2 on Mac OS X 10.6.4, it has very thin borders, compared to default print preferences e.g. in Preview. I think this was not always this way.

Also, when scaling to e.g. 90% in Preview, the content is centered on the page, in Safari, it's moved to the upper left.

Is this working as intended, or is something wrong on my system? How can I fix it?

[image: Screenshot of print dialog with page preview]

Comment: Is it solved? I'm facing the same issue on an M1 MacBook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the seems to be intended behavior. I haven't been able to get Safari to pay attention to regular margins, custom margins, hacked PPDs or user style sheets.